# undefined method `replies_path' RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am literally pulling my hair out over here.
I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I did some tutorials and projects then decided to start off on my own on my own great project.
I got pretty far and am now adding Comments to my Tutorials...

(My "logic" got very confused. In my code, a comment is actually an answer to a "post." a reply is a "comment" to a tutorial.")

I used the Rails Console to create a reply. And that worked fine. So then I added the code "copy and pasted from an earlier project" using simple_form_for to create a comment on the tutorial page.

```
    = simple_form_for(@reply, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |c|
    = c.input :content, :label => false
    = c.hidden_field :tutorial_id, :value => @tutorial.id
```

But when I reload my tutorial show page I get this error.

```
 NoMethodError in Tutorials#show 
 Showing /home/gilbert/Rails_Projects/Seek-Rails-master/app/views/tutorials/show.html.haml where line #13 raised:
undefined method `replies_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc519554cf0>:0x007fc5182f7b70>
Did you mean?  replys_path
           reply_path
```

I'm bad enough at what I'm doing that I don't know totally what all to describe...

I think part of the problem might be a large confusion between "reply and *replys*" vs "reply and *replies*"
maybe.

Here is my tutorial_controller.rb

```
class TutorialsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

def index
    @all_tutorials = Tutorial.all
    # @current_user_tuts = current_user.tutorials
    # # @current_user_tuts = current_user.tutorials
end

def show
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id]) 
    @replys = @tutorial.replys
    @reply = Reply.new
end

def new
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new
end

def edit
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new(create_params)
    if @tutorial.save
        redirect_to tutorial_path(@tutorial), notice: "Tutorial Created Succesfully."
    else
        redirect_to :back, flash: "Aw Snap! Error saving Tutorial. Try again Later."
    end
end

def create_params
    params.require(:tutorial).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
end

def destroy
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
    if @tutorial.delete
        redirect_to "/posts/profile", notice: "Tutorial Deleted"
    else
        redirect_to "/posts/profile", notice: "Error deleting Tutorial, please try again."
    end
end

def new_reply
    @reply = Reply.new
end
end
```

And my replys_controller.rb

```
class ReplysController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

def new
    @reply = Reply.new
end

def create
    @reply = Reply.new(create_params)
    if @reply.save
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Comment Created Succesfully."
    else
        redirect_to :back, flash: "Aw Snap! Error saving Comment. Try again Later."
    end
end

def create_params
    params.require(:reply).permit(:content, :tutorial_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

and Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "posts#index"
  get "/posts/forum" => "posts#forum"
  get "/posts/profile" => "posts#profile"
  get "/posts/edit" => "posts#edit"
  get "/posts/search" => "posts#search"
  get "/tutorials/index" => "tutorials#index"
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  resources :tutorials
  resources :replys
end
```

and reply.rb    (model)

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :tutorial
end
```

and tutorial.rb   (model)

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :replys
end
```

Sorry for the long post. I was hoping that it would suddenly come to me as I wrote it but it didn't.
I'd really appreciate the time spent on debugging this.
My code is also on github if you want to look at it or fork it or whatever...
https://github.com/GilGiy/Walk-Rails/tree/master/app

And if you have any tips about my code or something I'm doing completely wrong plz tell me...

Thanks a lot for you time....

Gil

EDIT:

Here's the output of "rake routes | grep replys"

```
                  replys GET    /replys(.:format)              replys#index
                     POST   /replys(.:format)              replys#create
           new_reply GET    /replys/new(.:format)          replys#new
          edit_reply GET    /replys/:id/edit(.:format)     replys#edit
               reply GET    /replys/:id(.:format)          replys#show
                     PATCH  /replys/:id(.:format)          replys#update
                     PUT    /replys/:id(.:format)          replys#update
                     DELETE /replys/:id(.:format)          replys#destroy
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes | grep replys`?

Comment: okay I just edited my post and added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with you route `resources :replys`.

Your model name is `Reply` and its plural is `replies` so when you create a form with:

```
simple_form_for @reply
```

Rails will detect that `@reply` is a `Reply` object and try to create a path automatically by pluralizing the name i.e `replies_path` but you don't have that route, instead you have `replys_path` so its giving the error.

Though you can explicitly mention the `url` and change the path to correct one, I would highly suggest you to change the route to `resources :replies` to avoid this kind of problem in future.

Comment: So I changed it to "resource :replies"

Comment: Sorry wasn't done typing. So I changed it but now I'm getting another error. Undefined method 'replys.' Pointing to line 13 in my tutorials_controller. @replys = tutorial.replys .

Comment: Maybe you missed something. But I think first you should change the all the `replys` to `replies` including controller names, actions, migrations etc wherever you have that word. Rails woks on convention over configuration so in most cases it will look for `replies` as that is correct plural throw errors when it cant find.

Comment: okay. I have a bunch of work I need to get to right now but i'll try again later tonight.

Comment: Sure, it might not be the cause of error but its sure a smell for trouble so fix it first

Comment: I replaced all replys with replies and it works fine. Thanks a bunch for your help...